# Errorlevel 0 after imagemagick batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to check whether an ImageMagick command completed successfully or not, using errorlevel.
However, I only get errorlevel 0. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::setting %file% and %outputfile% here, not relevant

ECHO error: %ERRORLEVEL%
magick convert "%file%" -crop 200x200+100+100 -threshold 50%% -define png:color-type=3 -define png:bit-depth=1 %outputname%
ECHO error: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

When `file` is a file smaller than 300x300, the magick command prints `` convert: invalid profile length `file.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1748. `` All echo commands output 0 however.

Things I've tried:

- Using delayed expansion, replacing `%ERRORLEVEL%` with `!ERRORLEVEL!`
- Lowercase `!errorlevel!`
- Putting  `&& ECHO success || ECHO failure` behind the magick line (this printed success)
- Adding `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( ECHO oops )` on the line after the magick line (didn't print anything)

This leads me to believe that the error in the magick command does not actually set errorlevel to something nonzero, but is there another way to check if the command encountered problems?

Comment: What comes to mind is piping the output into a separate file, checking if the output contains errors, and then doing x in case of errors (and y otherwise). I'm not sure how I would make that in a batch file though, and if it's possible I'd rather not create extra files.

Comment: Just a guess, try dropping `convert` from your command altogether and adding instead `-regard-warnings`

Comment: @MarkSetchell that worked, thanks! If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Version 7 **ImageMagick** commands have the format `magick INPUTIMAGE operations OUTPUTIMAGE`. If you use `magick convert INPUTIMAGE operations OUTPTIMAGE` you are forcing (less desirable) version 6 behaviour so you almost never want that.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why both `magick convert` and `magick` seemed to do the same

Comment: `SETLOCAL SetDelayedExpansion` is not a valid command!

Comment: @Compo oops, in my actual file I wrote EnableDelayedExpansion, not sure why I used set here

Comment: The only reasonable reason I can think of, is that you have not posted the actual code you're using, _(which would be a simple copy and paste operation)_! BTW, as you've decided that the variables you're using are not relevant, I'd suggest your `magick` command uses `"%outputname%"`, i.e. doublequoted, like your `"%file%"` variable.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it seems like `-regard-errors` does nothing when `magick` is used instead of `magick convert`, if I have the exact same code but remove convert all I get is errorlevel 0, whereas I get errorlevel 1 with the convert command. Not sure how recent this is, but it is described here: https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli

Comment: pipe to `find` or `findstr`: `magick convert all the parameters | find "warning"` (or preferably find the string when the operation was successful)

Comment: Yes, looks like `magick` doesn't set `ErrorLevel`, but does it output error messages at _STDERR_ (you can find that out by provoking an error and then appending `2> nul` to the comand line once and once not and see whether there is a difference)? if so you could do `magick … 2>&1 1> con | find /V "" && (echo Failure!) || (echo Success.)`…

Comment: I am unable to check as I don't have Windows, so please feel free to go ahead and write up an answer yourself summarising what you have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick warnings don't increase the errorlevel, the `-regard-warnings` option must be added to the command to do so (thanks Mark!)

However, the `magick` command, which replaces `magick convert` and other commands in ImageMagick 7 and later, does not seem to have a working `-regards-warnings` option right now: https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli. Therefore, `magick convert -regard-warnings [other options]` must be used in this case.

Comment: Apparently I can only accept this answer in two days, feel free to remind me if I haven't done so by then

Comment: Well done, and thank you for sharing back with the Stack Overflow community.